# Multiplication of elements in an Array

Tags: arrays, multiplication

I am trying to solve a problem. We shall find the maxProduct of an array, in O(n), so there are no double for loops allowed since it would be O(n²)
You will see in my code, that all the elements are multiplicated together except for the first and last elements. How can I multipliy the first and last element of my array using the logic of my code?

here is my code:

```
public class Maxprod {
public static void main(String [] args){
    Maxprod myclass = new Maxprod();
    myclass.maxProduct();
}

public void maxProduct(){
    int [] myarr = {4, -5, -7, 5};
    int max = 0, p=0;
    int q = 0;

    for(int i=0; i <myarr.length-1; i++){
        p = myarr[i]*myarr[i+1]; // 4 * 5 is missing here
        if (p > max){
            max = p;
        }
    }
    System.out.println(max);
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code situation seems worse than you thought; from what I see you miss not only (4 * 5), but also (4 * -7) and (-5 * -5).  Are you sure you only want consecutive numbers? You also miss (-7 * 5), because your for loop condition is off by one.

To answer your most direct question, initialize p to (start * end):

```
p = myarr[0] * myarr[myarr.length-1];
for(int i=0; i <myarr.length; i++){
    p = myarr[i]*myarr[i+1]; // 4 * 5 is missing here
    if (p > max){
        max = p;
    }
}
System.out.println(max);
```

If you actually want maxProduct, considering all permutations, in O(n), you'll need to track the two greatest positive and two greatest negative numbers.  Consider something like this:

```
public void maxProduct(){
    int [] myarr = {4, -5, -7, 5};
    int max = 0, maxn = 0, maxp = 0;
    int n1 = 0, n2 = 0;
    int p1 = 0, p2 = 0;

    for(int i=0; i <myarr.length; i++){
        // Store greatest negative pair
        if (myarr[i] < n1) {
            n2 = n1;
            n1 = myarr[i];
        }

        // Store greatest positive pair
        if (myarr[i] > p1) {
            p2 = p1;
            p1 = myarr[i];
        }
    }

    maxn = n1 * n2;
    maxp = p1 * p2;
    if (maxn > maxp) {
        max = maxn;
    } else {
        max = maxp;
    }

    System.out.println(max);
}
```